# Left Join with Case

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am new to sql I am using PHP myadmin I am wondering if you someone could teach or help me how to put left join condition with case condition in query because individually both query is working fine but when mixed together it is not working

here is the query

```
SELECT id, address,
        CASE
            WHEN <condition here>
            WHEN <condition here>
        END AS con1
FROM tblA WHERE address != ''
```

query to left join without case

```
SELECT tblA.id as Id, tblA.Address as Address, tblB.Status as Status 
FROM tblA 
LEFT JOIN tblB ON tblA.id=tblB.location
```

output for this query is

```
   id         Address     Status
    1222       add1       completed
    1332       add2       used
    1332       add2       completed
    1555       add3 
    1776       add4
```

I am finding hard time to join the sql query together can anyone explain or teach me how I am trying to put it like this

```
SELECT tblA.id, tblA.address, tblB.Status,

CASE WHEN address = 'vip' THEN 'vip'
        ELSE NULL END AS con1

    FROM tblA  LEFT JOIN tblB ON tblA.id=tblB.location
```

which is incorrect

Comment: What error are you getting?  Do you have any common field names between two tables? If yes, you need to tell the system what table to retrieve its value from.

Comment: #1109 - Unknown table 'tblB' in field list

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your actual query or fill-out the case statement?

Comment: Hi thank you I editted it

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: sorry fixed it already thank you for being nice and willing to help

Comment: @rrr . . . If the question is no longer relevant, you should delete it.